# login session current date

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, authentication

I want when someone log in to insert current time into database, I figured it out like this

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row->id;


   // updating last login 

            $time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$stmt = Config::$g_con->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastOn = :lastOn WHERE Name = :name");
 $stmt->bindParam(':lastOn', $time); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $row->id);
 //$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username']); 
 $stmt->execute();
```

but doesn't work, I mean it doesn't insert anythig in database.

Comment: Trying to be used id . Instead of Name

Comment: Yeah, finally I realized I was using ID not Name as user session.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = Config::$g_con->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastOn = :lastOn WHERE id = :name");
 $stmt->bindParam(':lastOn', $time); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_SESSION['user']); 
 $stmt->execute();
```